# How can I set sql driver for Oracle Adf Application module browser

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm using JDeveloper 11g and I've created an ADF ApplicationModule that connects to SQL Server. When I want to run the application module browser, it shows an error that it can not find the appropriate driver. What should I do?

Comment: Would you please provide the full error message or any stack trace if you have any?

Comment: (oracle.jbo.DMLException) JBO-26061: Error while opening JDBC Connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

In ApplicationModule configuration, in **local** section, `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` value should be added to `jbo.sql92.jdbcDriverClass` property.

Also `sqljdbc4.jar` library should be add to project libraries.